# How to Validate Angular 2 FormArray for length and Regex

Tags: angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl,FormGroup,FormArray,FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  form=new FormGroup({
    topics:new FormArray([])
  })

  addTopic(topic:HTMLInputElement){
    (this.form.get('topics') as FormArray).push(new FormControl(topic.value));
    topic.value='';
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<form>
<input type="text" class="form-control" (keyup.enter)="this.addTopic(topic)" #topic />
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let topic of form.get('topics').controls">
    {{topic.value}}
  </li> 
</ul>
</form>
```

I have created a Multi Input Control using Angular FormArray but how can i Validate the same for Minimum 2 Items(Length=2) and only accept integer values.
How to Add Validators.minlength like Reactive Form / Model Driven Form Approach.
How can i get those items using ngModel?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder
} from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  form = new FormGroup({
    topics: new FormArray(this.formBuilder.control(''), [Validators.reqired, Valiadtors.minlength(2)], Validators.Paterrn("^[0-9]*$"))
  ])

  addTopic(topic: HTMLInputElement) {
    (this.form.get('topics') as FormArray).push(new FormControl(topic.value));
    topic.value = '';
  }
}
```